# jquery hovering background bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I ran into this problem where I have h6s and when you hover over them, the background turns grey (opacity: 0.25;) and when you hover out, the background turns transparent again. Then, when you click on it, the background turns grey and stays that way. For some reason, when I hover over a different h6, the background doesn't turn grey.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topic_list = {
    0: "HOMEPAGE",
    1: "WHAT HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS ARE",
    2: "WHEN AND WHERE THIS HAPPENED",
    3: "OUR IDEAS",
    4: "PROS AND CONS",
    5: "OUR DETAILED ESSAY ON HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS",
    6: "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"
  };

  for (i in topic_list) {
    $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).hide();
  }

  $("#HOMEPAGE").show()

  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $("#header").append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory";
  }

  $(".topics").click(function() {
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (this.id == topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeIn();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)")
      } else {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "transparent")
      }
    }
  });

  $("#directory_link").click(function() {
    $("#WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE").fadeIn();
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") != "WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat, Trebuchet MS;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h6:hover {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25);
}

h6 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

header {
  background: #1d29c4;
}

#header {
  background: #202dd9;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <h1>HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS</h1>
</header>
<header id="header"></header>
<div id="HOMEPAGE">
  <p><i><b>sfdfdsasafd
</b></i></p>
  <p>afdsdfsfdsa</p>
  <p><i>asdfdsfafds</i></p>
  <p>sdfadfsdfs</p>
  <p>asdf <em>asf</em> <i id="directory_link">sfdadfas</i>? ...</p>
</div>
<div id="WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE">what</div>
<div id="WHEN_AND_WHERE_THIS_HAPPENED">when where</div>
<div id="OUR_IDEAS">ideas</div>
<div id="PROS_AND_CONS">procon</div>
<div id="OUR_DETAILED_ESSAY_ON_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS">a</div>
<div id="CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES">cred</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty complicated and could be refactored significantly by doing this with unobtrusive way. But the problem you have is that after click you are setting inline style, `background-color: transparent` and that will prevent the css-hover from happening. So to fix this, remove the inline `background-color` instead. You can do this by adding empty string as a value to .css-function:

```
$("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topic_list = {
    0: "HOMEPAGE",
    1: "WHAT HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS ARE",
    2: "WHEN AND WHERE THIS HAPPENED",
    3: "OUR IDEAS",
    4: "PROS AND CONS",
    5: "OUR DETAILED ESSAY ON HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS",
    6: "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"
  };

  for (i in topic_list) {
    $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).hide();
  }

  $("#HOMEPAGE").show()

  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $("#header").append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory";
  }

  $(".topics").click(function() {
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (this.id == topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeIn();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)")
      } else {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "")
      }
    }
  });

  $("#directory_link").click(function() {
    $("#WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE").fadeIn();
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") != "WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat, Trebuchet MS;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h6:hover {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25);
}

h6 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

header {
  background: #1d29c4;
}

#header {
  background: #202dd9;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <h1>HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS</h1>
</header>
<header id="header"></header>
<div id="HOMEPAGE">
  <p><i><b>sfdfdsasafd
</b></i></p>
  <p>afdsdfsfdsa</p>
  <p><i>asdfdsfafds</i></p>
  <p>sdfadfsdfs</p>
  <p>But, what <em>are</em> <i id="directory_link">hydrometeorological biohazards</i>? ...</p>
</div>
<div id="WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE">what</div>
<div id="WHEN_AND_WHERE_THIS_HAPPENED">when where</div>
<div id="OUR_IDEAS">ideas</div>
<div id="PROS_AND_CONS">procon</div>
<div id="OUR_DETAILED_ESSAY_ON_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS">a</div>
<div id="CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES">cred</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The style you set in function override the style you set in css

[image]

To prevent override do not set color :

`$("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "")`

(It's better than use `!important` in css)

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var topic_list = {0: "HOMEPAGE", 1: "WHAT HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS ARE", 2: "WHEN AND WHERE THIS HAPPENED", 3: "OUR IDEAS", 4: "PROS AND CONS", 5: "OUR DETAILED ESSAY ON HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS", 6: "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"};

    for (i in topic_list) {
     $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).hide();
    }

    $("#HOMEPAGE").show()

    for (var i in topic_list) {
     var element = document.createElement("h6");
     var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
     $(element).append(node);
     $("#header").append(element);
     element.className = "topics";
     element.id = topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory";
    }

    $(".topics").click(function() {
     for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (this.id == topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory") {
       $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeIn();
       $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)")
      } else {
       $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
       $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "")
      }
     }
    });

    $("#directory_link").click(function() {
     $("#WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE").fadeIn();
     for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") != "WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE") {
       $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
      }
     }
    });
   });
```

```css
   * {
    font-family: Montserrat, Trebuchet MS;
   }

   body {
    margin: 0px;
    background: white;
   }

   h1 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }

   h6:hover {
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25);
   }

   h6 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.4s;
   }

   header {
    background: #1d29c4;
   }

   #header {
    background: #202dd9;
    text-align: center;
   }

   div {
    position: absolute;
   }

   p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
   }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
   <h1>HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS</h1>
  </header>
  
  <header id = "header"></header>

  <div id = "HOMEPAGE">
   <p><i><b>sfdfdsasafd
</b></i></p>
   <p>afdsdfsfdsa</p>
   <p><i>asdfdsfafds</i></p>
   <p>sdfadfsdfs</p>
   <p>But, what <em>are</em> <i id = "directory_link">hydrometeorological biohazards</i>? ...</p>
  </div>

  <div id = "WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE">what
  </div>

  <div id = "WHEN_AND_WHERE_THIS_HAPPENED">when where
  </div>

  <div id = "OUR_IDEAS">ideas
  </div>

  <div id = "PROS_AND_CONS">procon
  </div>

  <div id = "OUR_DETAILED_ESSAY_ON_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS">a
  </div>

  <div id = "CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES">cred
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with you jquery onclick event jquery adding `background:transparent` to every `h6`.

i have added !important to `h6` as shown below:

```
h6:hover {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)!important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topic_list = {
    0: "HOMEPAGE",
    1: "WHAT HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS ARE",
    2: "WHEN AND WHERE THIS HAPPENED",
    3: "OUR IDEAS",
    4: "PROS AND CONS",
    5: "OUR DETAILED ESSAY ON HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS",
    6: "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"
  };

  for (i in topic_list) {
    $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).hide();
  }

  $("#HOMEPAGE").show()

  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $("#header").append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory";
  }

  $(".topics").click(function() {
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (this.id == topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeIn();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)")
      } else {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory").css("background", "transparent")
      }
    }
  });

  $("#directory_link").click(function() {
    $("#WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE").fadeIn();
    for (var i in topic_list) {
      if (topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") != "WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE") {
        $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Montserrat, Trebuchet MS;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h6:hover {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.25)!important;
}

h6 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

header {
  background: #1d29c4;
}

#header {
  background: #202dd9;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hydrometeorological Biohazards</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARDS</h1>
  </header>

  <header id="header"></header>

  <div id="HOMEPAGE">
    <p><i><b>sfdfdsasafd
</b></i></p>
    <p>afdsdfsfdsa</p>
    <p><i>asdfdsfafds</i></p>
    <p>sdfadfsdfs</p>
    <p>But, what <em>are</em> <i id="directory_link">hydrometeorological biohazards</i>? ...</p>
  </div>

  <div id="WHAT_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS_ARE">what
  </div>

  <div id="WHEN_AND_WHERE_THIS_HAPPENED">when where
  </div>

  <div id="OUR_IDEAS">ideas
  </div>

  <div id="PROS_AND_CONS">procon
  </div>

  <div id="OUR_DETAILED_ESSAY_ON_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARDS">a
  </div>

  <div id="CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES">cred
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use some touch-ups, but I used what you wrote.
Try this:

```
$(".topics").click(function(e) {
    // Set an "active" class for an active state
    $(".topics").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    for (var i in topic_list) {
        if (this.id == topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_") + "_directory") {
            $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#" + topic_list[i].split(" ").join("_")).fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```